# How to extract this with regular expressions in C#

Tags: c#, regex, outlook-addin, expression

I'm recently making an AddIn for Outklook in C#.
I started to see regular expressions.
I have one text like the next one (plain text in a string or a txt file), and I have to extract everything except what is after the `*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*` up to the word `HelpDesk`. How can I extract that with regular functions (or if not, how to extract the "message"?)? Thanks.

The text:

```
Bonjour,

Le ticket 271068 a été assigné à votre groupe SECURITY

    Date :         5/2/2013 4:07:09 PM 
    Demandeur:     LastName Name
    Utilisateur :  LastName Name
    Catégorie :    Security-Mail spam
    Niveau d'urgence: 

    Détails :

    Subject: 

    Message: Bonjour,


Here comes a message that can be
of many lines and can contain
anything.


Merci




    From: SMTP:{Thierry.PROMTEAU@oecd.org}Thierry.PROMTEAU@oecd.org
    To:    help@oecd.org
    *-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*


Lien direct vers le ticket :
http://sde.main.oecd.org/sde/default.aspx?ModSeq=24&Sequence=271068&FormSeq=1030

Cordialement

L’équipe du Helpdesk
```

Answer (score 0):

If your pattern will always be :
     *-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*
Than you could try :

```
 string[] splittedText = Regex.Split(yourText, "*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*");

 string result = splittedText[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can "extract" it by *replacing* all the input by just the part you seek, capturing it in a group:

```
string content = Regex.Replace(input, ".*[*-]{50,60}(.*)HelpDesk.*", "$1");
```